# jssor arrow navigators used to change slide?

Tags: jquery, jssor

I have a JSSOR slider inspired by http://www.jssor.com/demos/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.html

When dragging the main slide, the thumbnail listing updates to highlight the slide showing.

On clicking the arrow sliders left or right, the thumbnails move by an offset amount. I'd like for the first slide visible in the new thumbnail listing to show as the active slide.

I've looked and there doesn't seem to be an option for this, what would be the easiest way to achieve this effect?

Here is my current options setup:

```
var options = {
        $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
        $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
        $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
        $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

            $Loop: 1,                                       //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
            $SpacingX: 14,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $SpacingY: 3,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $Cols: 4,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
            $Align: 0,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail,

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 4                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        }
```

Comment: The thumbnails are there for user to choose which slide to display. When a thumbnail is clicked, it will scroll to the corresponding slide, and the thumbnail become active.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to be able to make a thumbnail active when the user changes the thumbnails that are visible. By clicking the arrow to change the visible thumbnails, the user is essentially choosing to view another slide. I'd be happy to implement a change myself, just not sure how to get started after looking at the source.